# Timber library doesn't support "nav_menu_link_attributes" filter?

Tags: wordpress, filter, menu, menuitem, timber

I'm trying to use [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) to append something else to the "href" of a single menu item. Seems to me Timber library doesn't supports this filter?

My code works as expected with twentytwenty, however it does not takes effect to change the attribute when I switch the theme to [Gesso-WP](https://github.com/forumone/gesso-wp), that depends on Timber library. Also I cannot find any other filter than "nav_menu_css_class" inside the `MenuItem` class https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/MenuItem.php

```php
function filter_menu_item_href( $atts ) {
    if ( strpos( $atts['href'], 'site/SPageNavigator/my_account.html' ) !== false ) {
        $atts['href'] .= '?NEXTURL=' . home_url();
    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_menu_item_href' );
```

What are the filtering options on Timber to change this single attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally handled this by using ["wp_nav_menu_objects"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/). This filter is present in the `Menu` class from the Timber library plugin: https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/Menu.php

```php
function filter_menu_item_href( $menu ) {
    foreach ( $menu as $item ) {
        if ( strpos( $item->url, 'site/SPageNavigator/my_account.html' ) !== false ) {
            $item->url .= '?NEXTURL=' . home_url();
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'filter_menu_item_href' );
```